# Can I add custom data to a pyproject.toml file

Tags: python, python-packaging, pyproject.toml, toml

I am using the [toml](https://pypi.org/project/toml/) package to read my `pyproject.toml` file.
I want to add custom data which in this case I will read in my `docs/conf.py` file.
When I try and add a custom section I get errors and warnings from [Even Better TOML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tamasfe.even-better-toml) extension in Vs Code stating that my custom data is no allowed.

Example TOML section in `pyproject.toml`

```ini
[custom.metadata]
docs_name = "GUI Automation for windows"
docs_author = "myname"
docs_copyright = "2023"
docs_url= "https://someurl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
```

So, my question is: Is there a valid way of adding custom data to a `pyproject.toml` file?

Comment: Note that the `pyproject.toml` file is never installed. It is only available in your source code repository and in the source distributions (sdists).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `[tool.*]` table.

Quoting [PEP 518](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/#tool-table):

> The `[tool]` table is where any tool related to your Python project, not just build tools, can have users specify configuration data as long as they use a sub-table within `[tool]`, e.g. the flit tool would store its configuration in `[tool.flit]`.

Any tools that interpret `pyproject.toml` files will expect the `[tool]` sub-tables to contain arbitrary, tool-specific metadata. You should not have any issues populating a custom subtable with whatever project metadata you need.

In your case, something like this should work warning-free:

```
[tool.my_distribution_name]
docs_name = "GUI Automation for windows"
docs_author = "myname"
docs_copyright = "2023"
docs_url= "https://someurl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
```

Creating your own custom table is not permitted, since PEP 518 [reserves all top-level tables](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/#file-format) in `pyproject.toml`:

> Tables not specified in this PEP are reserved for future use by other PEPs.

Comment: Works great thank you. My repo can be found here https://github.com/Amourspirit/python-ooo-dev-tools-gui-win for anyone that wants to see an example of this.